# In "Mission Creep" (season 1, episode 3), why was it worth it to Sam Latimer to do what he did regarding his own men?

Tags: character, person-of-interest

In "Mission Creep" (season 1, episode 3), why was it worth it to Sam Latimer    (--SPOILER--)    to kill off his own men every few months to avoid turnover? If it's not the kind of gang that you only leave when you die, what's so awful for him about people leaving and getting replaced? Wouldn't people be put off from applying for criminal jobs with him by the fact that his underlings had a habit of getting killed (even if they didn't know by whom)?